# How do you make a stacked bar plot in R with error bars on each bar for each variable that is stacked, and facet wrap?

Tags: r

I am trying to make a stacked bar plot in R with facet wrap, filled by variable, but am not able to stack the bars. So far, I am able to make a box plot but cannot stack the boxes.

Example data:

```
structure(list(place = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C"), person = c("Mica", "Mica", "Drew", "Sandra", "Tom", "Tom", 
"Nikata", "Beth", "Enrique"), value = c(95L, 96L, 94L, 70L, 78L, 
82L, 85L, 100L, 101L), variable = c("eng", "eng", "sci", "ma", 
"sci", "ma", "ar", "ar", "eng")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

```
ggplot(data, aes(place, value)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(color = variable))+
  facet_wrap(~person) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#3b3294","#f6cca0","#000000"))
```

Is it possible to stack the bars instead of them being side by side? Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify if you want a bar plot or a box plot? If you mean a stacked *box* plot (as in the title and in your code), do you have an example of what you're after? I've having trouble visualizing a clean stacked box plot in cases where there is overlap. If you are after a stacked *bar*plot, you can use the `position = "stack"` argument.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're looking for `geom_bar` and the `position` argument

```
ggplot(data, aes(place, value)) + 
  geom_col(aes(color = variable, fill = variable))
```

This will create stacked bar plots, while setting `position = dodge` will create bar plots side by side.

```
ggplot(data, aes(place, value)) + 
  geom_col(aes(color = variable, fill = variable), position = 'dodge')
```